# How to prevent the name of a man page from being truncated when using Vim as a man pager?

Tags: vim, man

Consider this shell command:

```
$ MANPAGER='vim -Nu NONE -R -' man git-credential-cache
```

It makes `man(1)` display the man page of `git-credential-cache(1)` in Vim.

However, the name of the man page – as displayed on the first line of the buffer – is `GIT-CREDENTIAL-CAC(1)`.
Notice how `HE` is missing at the end of the name:

[image: name of git-credential-cache man page is missing its last two characters]

I would expect this name instead:

```
GIT-CREDENTIAL-CACHE(1)
                  ^^
```

---

I ran `strace(1)` to see which system calls were used by `man(1)`:

```
$ MANPAGER='vim -Nu NONE -R -' strace -o log man git-credential-cache
```

Toward the end of the log file, I can see a `read(2)` and `write(2)` system call, using the buffer name `GIT-CREDENTIAL-CAC(1)`:

```
read(7, "GIT-CREDENTIAL-CAC(1)           "..., 4096) = 2720
...
write(8, "GIT-CREDENTIAL-CAC(1)           "..., 2720) = 2720
```

So it seems that it's `man(1)` and not `vim(1)` which is truncating the name of the man page.

Here is the full contents of the [log file](https://0x0.st/zyXH.txt), another [log file](https://0x0.st/zyXX.txt) containing the output of the same `strace(1)` command but with the additional `-f` argument to also trace the child processes, and the tree of processes leading to the `man(1)` process:

```
$ pstree -lsp $(pidof man)
systemd(1)---lightdm(947)---lightdm(1114)---upstart(1123)---sh(1324)---xfce4-session(1335)---xfce4-panel(1347)---panel-8-whisker(1396)---xterm(22546)---bash(22547)---strace(23182)---man(23184)---vim(23194)
```

---

Is there a way to prevent `man(1)` from truncating `GIT-CREDENTIAL-CACHE(1)` into `GIT-CREDENTIAL-CAC(1)`?

The reason why I ask this question is because the truncation causes an error message to be displayed when using the [Neovim man plugin](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/426399c2c4dd325bf00ffe1f410c1b9fd5053692/runtime/doc/filetype.txt#L554-L555):

```
            ┌ Taken from `:h man.vim` in Neovim
            ├────────┐
$ MANPAGER='nvim +Man!' man git-credential-cache
man.vim: command error (7) man -w git-credential-cac: No manual entry for git-credential-cac
```

[image: error in Neovim due to the truncation of the man page name]

---

Environment:

```
$  lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

$ man --version
man 2.7.5

$ vim --version | head -n2
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Sep  3 2019 11:05:36)
Included patches: 1-1967

$ nvim --version | head -n1
NVIM v0.4.0-1856-g82d52b229
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `man` who's truncating it either:

```
$ zcat /usr/share/man/man1/git-credential-cache.1.gz | head -n 10
'\" t
.\"     Title: git-credential-cache
.\"    Author: [FIXME: author] [see http://docbook.sf.net/el/author]
.\" Generator: DocBook XSL Stylesheets v1.79.1 <http://docbook.sf.net/>
.\"      Date: 09/28/2018
.\"    Manual: Git Manual
.\"    Source: Git 2.11.0
.\"  Language: English
.\"
.TH "GIT\-CREDENTIAL\-CAC" "1" "09/28/2018" "Git 2\&.11\&.0" "Git Manual"
```

So you'll have to fiddle with whatever `git` is using to generate its manpages and rebuild them (last time I had checked they were using `asciidoc` -- the sloowest thing in the universe ;-)).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'm still confused by something though. I don't know exactly how `man(1)` passes the man page to `nvim(1)`, but the latter reads a buffer whose name is initially `man://git-credential-cac(1)`. I guess this name is set by `man(1)` itself, because there is no code in the Nvim plugin which alters it prior to the autocmd listening to `BufReadCmd` (https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/3855204f5860ff2a66133541ff7593f0c2606a75/runtime/plugin/man.vim#L14).

Comment: Does it mean that `man(1)` uses the truncated command name written in the header inside the man page to set the name of the buffer/file that it passes to `nvim(1)`, and ignores the full command name that I typed after `$ man`?

Comment: 1. no, the buffer name is set by vim, in the [`man#open_page`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/3855204f5860ff2a66133541ff7593f0c2606a75/runtime/autoload/man.vim#L68) function called just before your link 2. man passes the data to `vim` through a pipe, it doesn't use any kind of named buffers, you can try with `MANPAGER=cat`. The strace output from your Q shows data actually read or written, not "buffer names". Simple example `printf "some text" | strace -e trace=read cat >/dev/null`.

Comment: Oh, you're right. So the issue is that Nvim relies on the header to guess the name of the man page:
https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/3855204f5860ff2a66133541ff7593f0c2606a75/runtime/autoload/man.vim#L398

Comment: At least on linux, it could better use the `MAN_PN` environment variable.